# How to conditionally redirect DNS queries by server with dnsmasq?

Tags: dnsmasq

I would like to know if it is possible to create a conditional redirect like:

```
# all domains *.lan
address=*.lan
server=192.168.1.254

# rest of all
address=
server 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [discussed extensively](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) in the documentation. Essentially you have to specify an upstream server using the **-S, --local, --server=[/[]/[domain/]][<ipaddr>...** syntax.

So something like

```
--server=/lan/192.0.2.10
```

would direct all queries for the lan domain to 192.0.2.10 and all other queries to the upstream servers as specified in the /etc/resolv.conf file or elsewhere.